# Does giving donations necessarily mean it's tzeddakah?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, tzedakah-charity, contradiction, contemporary-halacha

BS"D

How can giving a donation (based on US law that it is a contribution towards a non-for-profit 501c3 organization) to a very affluent *shul*, *yeshiva*, or other *mosed* still Halachically count as fulfilling the mitzvah of *tzedakah*?

**Please provide sources.**

Comment: https://www.myjewishlearning.com/mixed-multitudes/what-really-counts-as-tzedakah/ (external) also related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/109024/what-constitutes-tzedakah some sources https://www.sefaria.org/sheets/113902?lang=bi

Comment: @rosends Thanks for the sources. These sources don't entirely address if the wealth of the organization counts. Does that make sense? That is the gist of my question.

Comment: The wealth of the organization would not matter as long as the money is used properly.

Comment: @sabbahillel what's your source?

Comment: I once saw a Chazon Ish who discusses this... I don't remember the exact location; I saw it in the black edition of collected pieces al seder hadaf, IIRC on Nedarim 8a. Will post if I can find it...

Comment: Maybe it doesn't?