# Who takes priority when giving Tzedakah

Tags: halacha, tzedakah-charity

I have recently been hit with some financial issues, so I have to tighten my wallet.

Who takes priority in the giving of Tzedakah?

Comment: עניי עירך קודמים

Comment: highly related (duplicate?): https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/109043/11501

Comment: see also: [How to distribute tzedakah percentage wise?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/102083/how-to-distribute-tzedakah-percentage-wise) and the last link (https://dinonline.org/2010/08/12/laws-of-tzedakah-part-ii-who-to-give-first/)

Comment: on why Israel deserves tsedaka despite being far away for some: [How can tzedakah to the needy of Israel be justified?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/93244/11501)

Comment: Yourself.......

Comment: הגה: פרנסת עצמו קודמת לכל אדם, ואינו חייב לתת צדקה עד שיהיה לו פרנסתו

Comment: @sam -- Not quite.  Even a poor person dependent on charity must himself give *some* charity.  See, e.g., https://baishavaad.org/does-someone-taking-tzedakah-have-to-give-tzedakah/

Comment: You are referring to the shlish hashekel which is for the poor too,the Rama is talking beyond that chiuyv

Answer (score 1):

Relatives have priority over strangers in receiving charity. The poor of one's own community have priority over others.  And the poor of Eretz Yisrael have priority over everybody else.  [Shulḥan Arukh, Yoreh Deah 251:3]

And in most cases women have priority over men in receiving charity.  [Shulḥan Arukh, Yoreh Deah 251:8]

Comment: Where does it say women have priority?

Comment: @shmosel --  I am sure I read that somewhere but I can't find it. I'll keep looking. At any rate, it's not in the reference I gave, so I deleted it for now.

Comment: @shmosel -- I found *one* source, but not the one I remember.  "In most instances, one should prioritize to provide tzedakah to a needy woman ahead of a man."  in https://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/6499

Comment: איש ואשה שבאו לשאול מזון -- מקדימין אשה לאיש. וכן אם באו לשאול כסות. וכן אם באו יתום ויתומה לינשא -- מקדימין להשיא היתומה. YD 251:8

Comment: @shmosel -- Another source:  "If a man and a woman come to ask for food, we first provide for the woman before the man. The same priority applies if they come to ask for clothing. If a male orphan and a female orphan need funds for weddings, we are obligated to first marry off the female orphan." and "We redeem women before men."  in https://www.ezrastorah.org/tzedaka_archives.php

Comment: @sam -- Thanks, Sam.  OK, I put it back in.  And *that* was my original source.